# Where can I find programs for practicing C and assembler(IA32)?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, ubuntu, x86

I have learnt C and Assembly(IA32) on Linux and I will also be learning a few more languages this year.
I want to make my fundamentals strong and for that I need some tips from you guys as in, **where will I find programs for practice?** so that I solve them and get more and more experience.

Any good **web links** that would help a novice programmer to improve and be confident about the language he/she is learning.

I try looking up for questions on websites but they are either too difficult or not meant for beginners.**I want some source which would help me to be more clear fundamentally and conceptually**.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start by coding some of the simpler [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems in C, and then translate them to assembly.  The problems get progressively more challenging as you go.

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/toc.html) has an on-line version of The Art of Assembly Language Programming by Randall Hyde, but without the laboratory exercises.  However it still includes a lot of code snippets, and Randy takes a high-level approach to assembly programming using macros which will be familiar to a C programmer.  (I worked with Randy nearly 30 years ago doing assembly language programming on the Apple II).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how "novice" you are, but I'll be suggesting the [UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do (recommended to me by an experienced programmer) is read really good code. The Linux kernel is written in C. You can go to http://www.oldlinux.org/ to study with the first version, which would probably be easier than the current one. Beyond that, I would recommend finding an open source project for C that interests you. Working on a real-world project that interests you is going to be the best way to grow your skills.